# Start VirtualBox vm via cmd.exe and hide the cmd.exe window just after

Tags: windows, virtualbox, batch-file, cmd.exe

The following command will start a Virtual Box VM in Headless mode:

```
"C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxHeadless.exe" --startvm Slack131
```

I have it in a .bat file. After double-clicking the .bat script the command gets executed, the vm runs and the cmd.exe window keeps open.

I saw a different behavior with a MySQL server I've used some time ago. The idea was the same, to start it with a script. But in the MySQL case, the cmd.exe window disappeared just after the script was executed.

I would like to have the disappear effect in the Virtual Box vm starter script. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

`start "" "C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxHeadless.exe" --startvm Slack131`

The `start` command will run VirtualBox asynchronously, then the batch file will continue its own execution and close right away (assuming there are no further commands after `start`).

The first pair of quotes `""` is required by the `start` syntax (which takes the first quoted argument to be the new window title).

---

[ EDIT ]   The one-liner `start` command suffices in the usual cases when the batch file, say `runVBox.cmd`, is executed directly or via the equivalent of `cmd /c` (execute and terminate) e.g.

- execute directly at the cmd prompt: `runVBox.cmd`
- call from another batch file: `call runVBox.cmd`
- explicitly run via cmd/c: `cmd /c runVBox.cmd`
- double click in explorer

However, if called in a context equivalent to `cmd /k` (execute and remain) e.g.

- `start "" runVBox.cmd`
- `cmd /k runVBox.cmd`

then an additional `exit` is required at the end of `runVBox.cmd` to close the parent `cmd` process.

Comment: cmd.exe window still there.

Comment: Please post the entire batch file.

Comment: That one line is everything.

Comment: Depending on how you run it, you may need to add a 2nd line with just `exit`.